# Sample react app with inputs and post data to server

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Example:
I have a 3 rows

```
input EN | input RU | [submit]
input EN | input RU | [submit]
input EN | input RU | [submit]

[submit all]
```

How I can do it with react lib? How much components I need? Input EN,Input RU will have something more actions in future (like tooltips)

I would like to:
change 'input EN', or 'input RU' or together and after click on 'submit' send data to server.
Or I would like to change something and submit all, via click on 'submit all'

I check commentBox component in React docs, and now I can show some lines from server, but I don't understand, how I need to change data. Where I can set state? Where I need to trigger some events? And etc...

Comment: Can you clarify your question? It is hard to know exactly wha you want. You want to have independent submit per row + submit all.

Comment: @JeremyD you right... Hm, how I can explain it more?)
I have page with inputs group.
Every row is 2 inputs + button for submit current row changes
After all - one button for submit all changes.

Comment: What do you have so far? in terms of code. I think you will have a ParentComponent passing a click callback/submit callback to each of its children. But you will need to do some manual data fecthing in each input anyway, so the code is going to be verbose at the end.